# Error: Module version mismatch. Expected 47, got 48

Tags: node.js, visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I'm writing a Visual Studio Code extension which uses a native node.js module. When I try to debug this extension in vscode I get the error message from above, when loading the native module (when commenting out the `require()` call no error comes up). It tried quite a few steps to overcome + test this:

- `npm uninstall native-module` followed by a `npm install native-module --save-dev` in my vscode extension folder, this compiled the native module completely and without problems.
- Completely cleaned my node_modules folder in the extension and did again the `npm install --save-dev`.
- Installed node.js again, both LTS and current. With LTS the error message changes to: expected 47, got 46.
- Installed latest vscode ([August recovery build](http://code.visualstudio.com/Updates#_151-recovery-build))
- Launched a node session in my vscode extension folder and loaded my native module. This works nicely.
- Read the various questions and comments here on SO. They mostly recommend what I described above.

Still, I cannot get vscode to accept my native module. What can I do? From the above steps it appears as if vscode has been built with a node.js version between current and LTS. Can I force my native module somehow to use a specific version?

Btw. what do those numbers 48, 47, 46 etc. actually mean? The node.js version is of course in the typical form: major.minor.build and nothing of that matches the above version numbers.

**Update:**

ok, I found what those numbers mean: https://nodejs.org/en/download/releases/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once you know what those numbers in the error message mean it's easy to solve the issue. Simply install the node.js version that is expected. In my case it's [node.js 5.12.0](https://nodejs.org/download/release/v5.12.0/).

Answer (score 2):

Remove `node_modules` folder

Run `npm update`

Then;

Run `npm install`

Comment: I faced a similar issue, I was able to resolve it with instruction above. so don't know the reason for the negative rating?